# Remove duplicate terms from column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, duplication

This the tags column where all terms should be listed only once. Would like to remove all additional words from this column. For example the below contant:

> Lakshmi Bar & Restaurant, Dining & Leisure, Restaurants, Restaurants- Multi Cuisine, Hotel, , East#West, Malad East, Dafftary Road, Mumbai, Maharashtra, Features, , Lakshmi Bar & Restaurant, Dining & Leisure, Restaurants, Restaurants- Multi Cuisine, Hotel, , East#West, Malad East, Dafftary Road, Mumbai, Maharashtra, Cuisines, , Lakshmi Bar & Restaurant, Dining & Leisure, Restaurants, Restaurants- Multi Cuisine, Hotel, , East#West, Malad East, Dafftary Road, Mumbai, Maharashtra, Services, , Lakshmi Bar & Restaurant, Dining & Leisure, Restaurants, Restaurants- Multi Cuisine, Hotel, , East#West, Malad East, Dafftary Road, Mumbai, Maharashtra, Meal For Two, , Lakshmi Bar & Restaurant, Dining & Leisure, Restaurants, Restaurants- Multi Cuisine, Hotel, , East#West, Malad East, Dafftary Road, Mumbai, Maharashtra, Last Order/Booking (P.M), , Lakshmi Bar & Restaurant, Dining & Leisure, Restaurants, Restaurants- Multi Cuisine, Hotel, , East#West, Malad East, Dafftary Road, Mumbai, Maharashtra, BookUrTableId,

Should show as below:

> Lakshmi Bar & Restaurant, Dining & Leisure, Restaurants, Restaurants- Multi Cuisine, Hotel, East, West, Malad East, Dafftary Road, Mumbai, Maharashtra, Features, Cuisines, Services, Meal For Two, Last Order/Booking (P.M), BookUrTableId

Where i tried to run the query and insert this into a table it gave an error as the content in this column was going too long and stops the execution of the query.

Also it would be preferred if i can get this done in mysql rather than using php or any other programming language.

Please help.

Comment: Don't store comma separated values in one column and you won't have that problem. You think I'm joking or this is a dumb comment? No, it's common practice. Read about normalization.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is created using but this is the tags column and i need it to be this way to further process. Can you please let me know if there is a query that i can use within a query that can further remove duplicate keywords/terms so that i can insert this into another table.

Comment: No, there's no simple query. Databases are not meant to do such work. Read in the value, process it with the programming language of your choice, update the table afterwards. But really, you don't need your table design this way and you don't want to have it this way. This problem is just the beginning, you will run into much more and worse trouble with this design. Again, read about normalization, ask here if you have trouble coming up with a good design (show what you tried)...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback tomborn. The output file is to create a csv file to import into wordpress. And this is the tags field. And wordpress should be storing this differently. But definitely consider your suggestion when i am designing a database in the future.

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned, the database is perhaps not the best place to accomplish this; however, it can be done, using a stored function.  You wouldn't want to rely on this in a live environment, bit it works.

If the following seems a bit primitive, that's an indication of the somewhat poor match between tool and task.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `dedup_csv` //
CREATE FUNCTION `dedup_csv` (in_str LONGTEXT) RETURNS LONGTEXT
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
BEGIN

-- http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87144/remove-duplicate-terms-from-column
-- given a comma-separated string of values, return a comma-separated string of
-- unique values found in the list

DECLARE out_str LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL; -- pending output
DECLARE next_str TEXT DEFAULT NULL;    -- next element under consideration

dedup:
LOOP

  IF CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(in_str)) = 0 OR in_str IS NULL THEN
    LEAVE dedup; -- no more data to consider
  END IF;

  SET next_str = SUBSTRING_INDEX(in_str,',',1);                   -- find the next element
  SET in_str = SUBSTRING(in_str FROM (CHAR_LENGTH(next_str) + 1 + 1)); -- remove that element

  SET in_str = TRIM(in_str), next_str = TRIM(next_str); -- trim the new and the rest

  IF FIND_IN_SET(next_str,out_str) OR CHAR_LENGTH(next_str) = 0 THEN -- if empty or already found
    ITERATE dedup;
  END IF;

  SET out_str = CONCAT_WS(',',out_str,next_str); -- append the new to pending output 

END LOOP;

RETURN out_str;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

See this live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32ee/1

The output from this function, given the input above:

```
Lakshmi Bar & Restaurant,Dining & Leisure,Restaurants,Restaurants- Multi Cuisine,Hotel,
East#West,Malad East,Dafftary Road,Mumbai,Maharashtra,Features,Cuisines,Services,Meal For Two,
Last Order/Booking (P.M),BookUrTableId
```

Leading and trailing spaces and empty values are cleaned up automatically.

```
mysql> SELECT dedup_csv('foo,bar,,,   ,baz,foo,  foo  , bar') AS deduped;
+-------------+
| deduped     |
+-------------+
| foo,bar,baz |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Again, the database not being the ideal tool is reflected in the benchmarks, which are highly dependent on input length and number of elements.

On the short and simple string shown above, the actual runtime on MySQL 5.5 on a 1 GHz Opteron 1218 is ~ 150 µsec, while the long string in the original question requires about 2400 µsec to process... which works out to a fairly substantial amount of time for large data sets.

Comment: The above answer works great. Just one note: If you are using special characters, you should replace all calls to LENGTH() function with CHAR_LENGTH().

Comment: @cgaffga thanks, that's definitely a good point. I've edited the answer accordingly.